# Can't get charAt(0) to work

Tags: java, string, if-statement, java.util.scanner

Ok, so I can't seem to get this to work, though many people have told me the syntax and logic is correct. Can anyone reveal for me what I could possibly be doing wrong?

```
public Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public void movePlayer() {
    System.out.print("move: ");
    String str = in.nextLine();

    in.nextLine();

    char c = str.charAt(0);

    if (c == 'l' || c == 'L') {
        player.moveLeft();
    }
 }
```

The program gets caught at char `c = str.charAt(0);`

And I am being returned this error:

**java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
String index out of range: 0 (in java.lang.String)**

Comment: Aaaaaand... did you try checking if str is not null ?

Comment: It means that str is empty (str == "") so there is no char at 0.

Comment: Not "not null", empty, sorry. Why do you have a second in.nextLine() with no affectation ? Is this intentional ?

Comment: I made a small java file from your code and it compiles correctly. Perphaps there is some thing else wrong . Paste your full code ( btw , i made Scanner static and code is executed in static void main)

Answer (score 5):

you did not input anything though the console, so `str` is empty. this is the reason why `chatAt(0)` throw an exception

Comment: @GregKopff The error message is pretty clear on that: you can only get that message if you do charAt on an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to use `nextLine()`.  You want to use `next()`.

```
String str = in.next();
```

This is the Javadoc for [`nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

You want [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) instead:

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

This will stop you from consuming the empty line and raising an exception.

Answer (score 0):

This means that `str` is empty. You should check if it is not `null` and not empty.

```
if (str != null && !str.isEmpty()) {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone :) got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

Add a check for Empty String and Null as well . You will avoid a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

If you press Enter key in console, `Scanner` will be considered a complete line, regardless of whether or not there is text entered.

Press Enter at the beginning of a line, returns a String `""` to the method [Scanner.nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29).

Add a check with `str.lenght () > 0` before `str.charAt(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `in.next()` instead. For whatever reason, `nextLine()` doesn't work with `CharAt()` sometimes.